# I want the text from list items to be in the same vertical left line as the first line going to the bottom

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljyqyosh/

What I want is to make the image check to be outside of the list items because I though I can make the paragraph to be in the same block (if that's a correct term), but it appears it is still below the image check.

Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="DIV_1">
    <ul id="UL_2">
        <li>Explore the impact of your past stories on who you are and what you love, so that you can bring those elements to life in your design.
        </li>
        <li>Discover how to make your style stand out, so that your spaces are truly unique, and memorable.
        </li>
        <li>Claim your Design Style for your home by creating your own Style Board, so that you know exactly what you’re aiming for throughout your project.
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    height: 76px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    width: 934px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    perspective-origin: 467px 38px;
    transform-origin: 467px 38px;
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}

ul li:before {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 43px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    width: 40px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    perspective-origin: 20px 21.5px;
    transform-origin: 20px 21.5px;
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://tdhdp.lineoclients.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/li-image.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It primarily solves what I intended to do, but I notice something here: https://jsfiddle.net/17uLufjw/

If I add margin, it's still there. I think it resides inside the before selector, im not sure.

The li to which has the second line changes the width of the image, resulting 40x43  changed to 30.641x41.

Any advice? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add below css code

```
ul li {
 display:flex;
}
ul li:before {
 margin-right:10px;
}
```

**[update jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljyqyosh/2/)**

Comment: It solves tha problem, no doubt. But I notice that whenever there's a second line text to each li will change the image size from 40x43 (orgininal) to 30.641x43.  jsfiddle.net/17uLufjw

Comment: just add `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://tdhdp.lineoclients.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/li-image.png") left center no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;` to your css part

Comment: you are using `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://tdhdp.lineoclients.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/li-image.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;` and no need to add last properties `(repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;)` for this just replace with upper comment properties

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: flex;` on the `li` will create 2 columns in a row.

```css
ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    height: 76px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    width: 934px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    perspective-origin: 467px 38px;
    transform-origin: 467px 38px;
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
    display: flex;
}

ul li:before {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    content: ' ';
    height: 43px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    width: 40px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    perspective-origin: 20px 21.5px;
    transform-origin: 20px 21.5px;
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://tdhdp.lineoclients.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/li-image.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 300 normal 18px / 26px Arial, sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
    margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="DIV_1">
 <ul id="UL_2">
  <li>Explore the impact of your past stories on who you are and what you love, so that you can bring those elements to life in your design.
  </li>
  <li>Discover how to make your style stand out, so that your spaces are truly unique, and memorable.
  </li>
  <li>Claim your Design Style for your home by creating your own Style Board, so that you know exactly what you’re aiming for throughout your project.
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, did you notice the images to those li that has the second line changes the width of it from  40x43 (orgininal) to 30.641x43?